# Parser Error Message: Could not load type : the file of the master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have the following error in parsing my web - based application:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Hamla.Masouma_Program'.

Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Masouma_Program.Master.cs" Inherits="Hamla.Masouma_Program" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html>
```

My web based application has master page and this is the header of the master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Masouma_Program.Master.cs" Inherits="Hamla.Masouma_Program" %>
```

problem is that it can not load the code under inherits.

The page is working fine in the programming mode, but once I put in inetpub/wwwroot/ it does not work and gives this error. Can you please help me to fix this error.

BR//

Comment: Did you build and publish the site?  How is it getting to inetpub/wwwroot?

Comment: No, I did not publish the site. I directly put it in the inetpub/wwwroot. Do I need to publish it?

Answer (score 3):

Read up on publishing ASP.NET websites.  You're not putting the compiled version of your site in wwwroot, that's why you are getting that error.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Dear bro, I have published the web site. Now, what to do? How to use it after the publish as there is not setup file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue to after making some modifications on my proj. and now its online again;
Instead of change the CodeBehind to CodeFile on your file.aspx, check Inherits;

On Inherits field:

```
Inherits="yourproject.yourfolder.yourfile"
```

one of my conf. file for ex:

```
Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RepConsult.aspx.cs" Inherits="Monit.Reporting.RepConsult"
```

In your case, you can try this:

```
CodeBehind="Masouma_Program.Master.cs" Inherits="Hamla.Masouma_Program.Master" %>
```